# React Native TextInput reads value from state when it's in string. But fails when it is in number

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I don't know whether it's a bug on react native `TextInput` or if I am doing something wrong. When I try to show initial value based on state as default value on TextInput it works only for string and not for number.

```
        this.state = {referralCode: 10}
<TextInput value={this.state.referralCode}  />
```

This due to some reason does not works and shows empty but it should read the intezer value from the state. As soon as I update the state with some string as initial value the TextInput shows it on initial render.

```
               this.state = {referralCode: 'Rishav'};

 <TextInput value={this.state.referralCode}
```

/>

It happens to render the initial state value now because it is in string.

Also,
 `<TextInput value={10}/>` fails but `<TextInput value={'10'}/>` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#value) . Value props need string . if you want to use number set in state , you can do like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      referralCode: 10
    };
  }

<TextInput
            onChangeText={referralCode => this.setState(referralCode)}
            value={`${this.state.referralCode}`}
            blurOnSubmit={true}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            returnKeyType="done"
          />
```

Comment: I laugh at myself for this silly mistake. Thankyou : )